# How to access R markdown stored in a package

Tags: r, knitr

I want to create a package that produces reports using knitr that uses predefined templates.

At the moment I have a project directory that has this structure

```
R/createReport.r
R/reportTemplate.rmd
```

inside `createReport.r` I want to be able do something like the following;

```
require(knitr)
render('reportTemplate.rmd', output.file='someplace')
```

However I have no idea how to get the `render` function to locate my template file. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the template in `yourpackage/inst/templates/sometemplate.Rmd` and then access it with:

```
system.file("templates/sometemplate.Rmd", package="yourpackage")
```

Comment: That's the function I needed! Thanks.